# Bottom coordinates of CListBox is not set correctly

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

MFC beginner question.

I created a listbox and a button using `CListBox::Create` and `CButton::Create` respectively, using `CRect` for their size and location.
The two `CRect` has the **same height**, but when they are shown in the screen, the height of the listbox is **shorter** than that of the button.

I checked the pixel coordinate using a mouse click event handler `OnLButtonDown`, and noticed that the size and location of the button are correct. The **bottom coordinate** of the CListBox is not correct. Why is this happening?

The option I used to create the listbox was `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | LBS_STANDARD`, and used `WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_PUSHBUTTON` for the button. I tried removing the `LBS_STANDARD`, but still the height was not changed.

The [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clistbox-class?view=msvc-170#create) on CListBox::Create just describes this:

> rect
>
> Specifies the list-box size and position. Can be either a CRect object or a RECT structure.

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `LBS_NOINTEGRALHEIGHT` style:

> Specifies that the size of the list box is exactly the size specified by the application when it created the list box. Normally, the system sizes a list box so that the list box does not display partial items.